# Opening links within jquery modal window

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, hyperlink

I am able to open a modal window by clicking on the link from test.html.
When the modal window opens, I am able to see content.

When I click on the links in the modal.html, all the links are opening in the parent window instead. What I want happens is when I click on a link that has the target = _blank, I want it to open in a new tab. When the target = _self, open the content within the same
modal window.

Can anyone help please. Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks

test.html markup

```
 <p> 
     <a class="open-modal" href="modal.html">Open Modal Window</a>
 </p>
```

modal.html markup

```
 <p>
     <a target="_parent" href="mypage.php">Open in parent</a>
 </p>

 <p>
     <a target="_blank" href="mypage.php">Open in new tab</a>
 </p>

 <p>
    <a target="_self" href="mypage.php">Open in same modal window</a>

 </p>
```

jquery.js code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {                


      $('a.open-modal').click(function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           $this = $(this);
           var URL     = $(this).attr('href');
           var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialog');
           var dialogOptions = {
                                height: 448,
                                width: 736,
                                modal: true,

      //   open: function(event, ui){

      //   },

           close: function(event, ui){
               $('#dialog').empty(); 
           }
      };

      if(dialogbox==null) {
          $this.after("<div id=\"dialog\"></div>");
      }

      jQuery('#dialog').load(URL + " #content").dialog(dialogOptions);


      });

});
```

Comment: Check this site out. It does exactly what you need to do 

http://oscarotero.com/jquery/

Comment: I only see a API reference guide. Is this the proper link?

Comment: yes! I mean the reference guide is actually a completely different site altogether but gets loaded in Iframe here.

Comment: Looks like the site you sent me is using an iframe within the modal. I am wondering can the linking within modal windows be used without using iFrames

Comment: in that case you'll need to add complete html and play around a bit with javascript to get those working on page load events. that is definitely doable. Look for Jquery load documentation. you'll find it there